# How to manage two repos of app code, only difference is ads with Git

Tags: android, git, versioning, ads

So this isnt specific to a code sample, but we have two apps, that are on the app market.  There is a paid and a free version.  The only difference is the free version has ads on one page.  Since the market is dependent on package names being different, how would you go about merging or managing this data if only one activity is different?  Right now, we just git pull from the ads version and then manually fix the package references.  Any ideas on where to learn about others suffering this workflow issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One other idea would be to manage only one branch with:

- files in packages named for the free version
- a script able to *generate* files in packages with the right name for the paid versions

If one content can easily be generated, then you might consider to versioning it.